axios response type: Why is it AxiosResponse<any, any>?
I have a simple axios query that has some weird type issue:
const stuff = {
  getItems: (): Promise<Item[]> => apiAxios.get(`/api/get-items`).then((data) => {
      return prepareItem(data)
  }),
}

const prepareItem = (
    data: Item[]
):Item[] => {
    return data.filter(({id}) => id === 123)
}

However, the data inside prepareItem(data) is underlined in red as a Typescript error. It says:
"The argument of type 'AxiosResponse<any, any>' cannot be assigned to the parameter of type 'Item[]'."
How can I get rid of Typescript interfering some AxiosResponse<any, any> type? I am declaring the return type to be a promise of type Item[] so why is it even assuming it could be AxiosResponse<any, any>?

edit: Ahhhh I noticed some other dev has created a wrapper for the axios calls:
const apiAxios = axios.create({ ...stuff... });
  const wrapReadMethod = fn => (url: string, params = {}, source = axios.CancelToken.source()) =>
    CancelPromise.setCancel(source.cancel)
      .then(() => fn(url, { params, cancelToken: source.token }))
      .then(res => res.data);

apiAxios.get = wrapReadMethod(apiAxios.get);

I wonder if there is a way to "drag through" the correct type?

Try .then(response => prepareItem(response.data)).

Put type to .get, like this:
const stuff = {
  getItems: () =>
    apiAxios
      .get<Item[]>(`/api/get-items`)
      .then((response) => prepareItem(response.data)),
};

It's called generic type in TypeScript.
